# Explanation needed: What is grammatically wrong in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

I'm having some difficulty identifying the grammar mistake in this sentence:

"The basketball coach had stood and watched his team all morning before he gave his advice."

My theory is that 'had stood' needs to be changed to 'had been standing'. Is this true? why/why not?

Comment: Well, it had the tag "Homework" but not sure why Laurel felt the need to edit that out. I know for a fact there is a mistake, but not what it is.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I have bad news for you: there is no mistake.

Comment: Hmm, if so ... Does the sentence sound funny? Is there a more "correct" way to phrase the sentence?

Comment: Is there a wider context that makes you think a perfect tense is appropriate here?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This is all I'm given.

Comment: In that case, you don't need the perfect tense at all. This is fine: _The basketball coach stood and watched his team all morning before he gave his advice_.

Comment: @javanewbie Please read the tag wiki, found by hovering over the tag: "This tag is officially deprecated and will be removed". See also the [meta discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2099/191178). Do not use the homework tag.

Comment: Please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”, and “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”, and the *[Writers Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)*.  If there is an unstated specific concern or uncertainty, such as a point of grammar or the meaning of an unfamiliar word, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you change "had stood" to "had been standing", then you could also change "and watched" to "and watching".

Next, consider changing "had stood" to the simple "stood".  Nothing changes meaning in any of these versions because the temporal adverbial "all morning" overrides any aspect.  The original sentence is not grammatically 'wrong', but the use of perfect aspect is superfluous.